# sum column with sum of joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables appointments and line_items.

```
appointments 
id integer primary key 
price decimal

line_items 
id integer primary key 
price decimal 
appointment_id integer foreign key
```

I need to get sum of appointments.price with sum of associated sum of line_items price.

For example, I have 2 appointments

```
id price 
1 10 
2 15
```

and line items

```
id price appointment_id
1  10    1
2  15    1
3  10    2
3  20    2
```

The total result should be (10 + (10 + 15)) + (15 + (10 + 20))

Currently I am trying this query. But it doesn't work.

```
SELECT SUM(appointments.price + sum(line_items.price)) AS total_sum
FROM `appointments`
  INNER JOIN 'line_items' ON 'line_items'.'appointment_id' = 'appointments'.'id'
```

What is best approach for this? Subquery for sum of line_items.price or joining sum line_items.price. Or there is another better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit your post with the definitions of your tables?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? At the minute you're subtracting each appointments.price from the sum (total) of line_items.price and then summing that up. Is that what you intended to do?

Comment: I can't imagine it is. You are going to get count(line_items) * appointments.price for your total appointment cost. seems wrong

Comment: I need to get sum of (appointment price + sum of associated line items price)

Comment: It would be good if you provide us sample data as well

Comment: @ChristianBarron I've edited post, now it has + instead of -, but your thought is right!

Comment: 3 answers, and not a fiddle between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you're looking for, it seems you were close to the answer:

```
SELECT SUM(app.price + IFNULL(li.price,0)) AS total_sum
FROM appointments app
  LEFT JOIN 
  (Select appointment_id, Sum(price) price from line_items group by appointment_id) li on li.appointment_id = app.id
```

Comment: Thanks! I have one question, what if there is no line_items of appointment.
I've tried LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, but I'm getting 0 even if appointment price is not 0. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Pavel the updated should work for this circumstance

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is a `SUM() GROUP BY` in a derived table and then a `join` with `appointments`. Something like this.

```
SELECT SUM(appointments.price + line_items.price) AS total_sum
FROM appointments
 INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT line_items.appointment_id,SUM(price) as price
line_items
GROUP BY appointment_id 
) line_items ON line_items.appointment_id = appointments.id
```

Comment: seems that you are selecting appointment_price, and total sum of joined line_items. But I need sum, should I just use sum(appointments.price + line_items.price) in select of your example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT appointments.id,(appointments.price + sum(line_items.price)) AS total_sum
 FROM appointments
 INNER JOIN line_items ON line_items.appointment_id = appointments.id
 group by appointments.id
```